# Problem with API for checking available slots and move the meeting

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a program that takes google meet with the google calendar api. My program asks for a time, day, and participants. This program should also automatically detect if I want to take a meeting in a time slot already used to shift it to a free slot. For example, I want to take a meeting from 12pm to 1pm, but I've already taken one from 11am to 12.15pm. The program should itself shift the meeting from 12:15pm to 1:15pm. But I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valereansel/Documents/APICALENDAR/tkintercreatmeetdispo.py", line 104, in <module>
    handle_form_submit(
  File "/Users/valereansel/Documents/APICALENDAR/tkintercreatmeetdispo.py", line 93, in handle_form_submit
    create_event(service, summary, location, description, start_datetime, end_datetime, attendees)
  File "/Users/valereansel/Documents/APICALENDAR/tkintercreatmeetdispo.py", line 65, in create_event
    ).execute()
      ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2023-08-09T12%3A00%3A00&timeMax=2023-08-09T12%3A45%3A00&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&alt=json returned "Bad Request". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request'}]">
```

I tried to do this:

```
import datetime
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']

def get_credentials():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                '/Users/valereansel/Documents/APICALENDAR/credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    return creds

def create_event(service, summary, location, description, start_datetime, end_datetime, attendees):
    event = {
        'summary': summary,
        'location': location,
        'description': description,
        'start': {
            'dateTime': start_datetime.isoformat(),
            'timeZone': 'Europe/Paris',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': end_datetime.isoformat(),
            'timeZone': 'Europe/Paris',
        },
        'attendees': [{'email': email} for email in attendees],
        'reminders': {
            'useDefault': False,
            'overrides': [
                {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
            ],
        },
        'conferenceData': {
            'createRequest': {
                'requestId': 'random-string-123',
                'conferenceSolutionKey': {
                    'type': 'hangoutsMeet'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    events_result = service.events().list(
        calendarId='primary',
        timeMin=start_datetime.isoformat(),
        timeMax=end_datetime.isoformat(),
        singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime',
    ).execute()

    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if events:
        for existing_event in events:
            existing_start = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(existing_event['start']['dateTime'])
            existing_end = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(existing_event['end']['dateTime'])

            if (existing_start <= start_datetime <= existing_end) or (existing_start <= end_datetime <= existing_end):
                duration = end_datetime - start_datetime
                start_datetime = existing_end
                end_datetime = start_datetime + duration

    created_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event,
                                            conferenceDataVersion=1).execute()
    meet_link = created_event['conferenceData']['entryPoints'][0]['uri']
    print('Event created: %s\nGoogle Meet Link: %s' % (created_event.get('htmlLink'), meet_link))

def handle_form_submit(summary, location, description, attendees, date, start_time, end_time):
    creds = get_credentials()
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(date, start_time)
    end_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(date, end_time)

    create_event(service, summary, location, description, start_datetime, end_datetime, attendees)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    summary = input('Enter event summary: ')
    location = input('Enter event location: ')
    description = input('Enter event description: ')
    attendees = input('Enter attendee emails (comma-separated): ').split(',')
    date = input('Enter event date (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
    start_time = input('Enter start time (HH:MM): ')
    end_time = input('Enter end time (HH:MM): ')

    handle_form_submit(
        summary,
        location,
        description,
        attendees,
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
        datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M').time(),
        datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, '%H:%M').time()
    )
```